# Get a JSON response and save to file using require.js

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

Im trying to make a plugin for require.js that allows me to call an external api, convert the json response and save it to a file.

Problems:

- Im not sure if I am writing the plugin correctly
- I cant seem to use node filesystem - though i am using r.js

I am hoping to do this on build, so that the file is ready before concat method happens (putting all files into one)

Is this even possible? Should I use a grunt task instead?
Any pointers or examples or tutorials or anything would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used, https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-curl.

Was alot easier, and just modified the file a bit to wrap the response in define();

It allows the files to be downloaded on build and required later in the app